# Derivative of this matrix expression?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-equations, chain-rule

Assume that I have the following expression:

$$f(x,c) = \int_{0}^{x}g(\mathbf{\Psi}(x)^\intercal\mathbf{c}) dx$$

where $f(x,c)$ is a scalar, $x$ is a scalar, $\mathbf{\Psi}(x)$ is a $N$-by-$1$ vector, $\mathbf{c}$ is a $N$-by-$1$ vector, and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a scalar-valued function. I'd like to know the partial derivatives of this expression with respect to $\mathbf{c}$:

$$\nabla_\mathbf{c}f(x,c) = ?$$

where $\nabla_\mathbf{c}=[\partial/\partial c_{1},...,\partial/\partial c_{N}]^\intercal$. Do you know how I could solve this? I would appreciate any full or partial solutions!

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbf{\Psi}(x)^\intercal \mathbf{c}$? Since $\mathbf{\Psi}(x)\mathbf{c}^\intercal$ is N-by-N not a scalar

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right! Yep, it should be a scalar. I have corrected it. Thank you!

Comment: [Leibniz Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) yields
$$\nabla_c f = \left[\int_0^x g'(\Phi^Tc)\;dx\right]\Phi$$

Comment: Oops, the $\Phi$ should not be outside of the integral, but inside of it.